# Uniswap V3: Create LP (ETH-ERC20 pair) using solidity

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

I am trying to create a Liquidity Pool using solidity with ETH and my custom ERC20 token. I’ve been struggling with this mainly because the example for V3 is a ERC20 to ERC20 pair.

Does Uniswap convert the ETH to WETH automatically or will I have to wrap my ETH before I create the pool for ETH/ERC20 token??

No code yet just trying to understand Uniswap V3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you refer to the official Uniswap V3 example here : https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/liquidity/adding and that your **pool is initialized**

**Short answer**: Uniswap handles the (un)wrapping.

**Complete answer** :

The main idea in adding liquidity is similar to how swaps are performed in V3:

- start from a periphery (optional) "helper" ([NonfungiblePositionManager.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol) here), which is inheriting [LiquidityManagement.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/80f26c86c57b8a5e4b913f42844d4c8bd274d058/contracts/base/LiquidityManagement.sol#L51) (from periphery/base). This is where you can find the (internal) addLiquidity function which, after computing the amount (price for start and end tick and Struct packing) will...
- ...call the low-level-ish mint function on the pool itself. This function is quite short, and can be summarized as: take note of the current pool balances - call the callback - take note and comparing the new pool balances.

The actual token transfers are done in the callback, which **must** be implemented by the contract calling pool.mint (here, [LiquidityManagement](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/80f26c86c57b8a5e4b913f42844d4c8bd274d058/contracts/base/LiquidityManagement.sol#L25) does it for you). The callback uses pay() (from [base/peripheryPayment](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/80f26c86c57b8a5e4b913f42844d4c8bd274d058/contracts/base/PeripheryPayments.sol#L52)), where you can easily see the (un)wrapping mechanism (pay is used by the swap callback too).

```
if (token == WETH9 && address(this).balance >= value) {
        // pay with WETH9
        IWETH9(WETH9).deposit{value: value}(); // wrap only what is needed to pay
        IWETH9(WETH9).transfer(recipient, value);
```

Control schema:

```
 Periphery                Core
addLiquidity      --->  pool.mint
mintCallback&Pay  <---  
                  --->  pool.mint
```

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely helpful. I have one final question. I am able to follow the control schema up until the "mintCallBack". Where/When is the callback function called? Does this happen during "pool.mint"?

Comment: Yes, here: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/c05a0e2c8c08c460fb4d05cfdda30b3ad8deeaac/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol#L482-L483

Don't forget to mark the question as answered then;)